# Ecmascript to read specific custom properties of library and based on the property value delete the item

Tags: javascript

ECMAScript to read specific custom properties of library and based on the property value delete the item.

```
   var itemId = 43;
             function filldata() {
                 var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
                 this.web = clientContext.get_web();
                 var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("doc lib name");
                 this.listItem = list.getItemById(itemId);
                 // clientContext.load(this.listItem, 'Include(Id, Description,Publih Date)'); //error message properties Description,PublihDate not available.
                 clientContext.load(this.listItem);
                 clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onFail));
    }

     function onSuccess(sender, args) {

                 var value = this.listItem.get_item("Title");  // Getting only ID , title .
     var value = this.listItem.get_item("Description"); // error like below
    var value = this.listItem.get_item("Publih Date");// error like below
                alert("value" + value);

    }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: For Description ,PublishedDate raising error like:- The property or field has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.

Comment: Please include this information into the question.

Answer (score 1):

This is internal names issue.  Description filed internal name is  Description0, Publih Date field name is Publih_x0020_Date.

Comment: If this completely solves your problem, please mark your answer as accepted.